# Mongoid associations not working but ids very well exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, appfog

I have a test app running at Appfog. Appfog docs suggest use of Mongomapper gem but I have used Mongoid for my project. https://docs.appfog.com/services/mongodb

Problem is:

Mongoid associations don't work but the ids are right there.

```
m = Movie.find_by(:name => "Argo")
m.actors
=> []
m.actor_ids
=> ["510a092553c205c294000040", "510a099b53c205c2940001ce", "510a09a553c205c2940001ef", "510a0a4653c205c2940003ca", "510a0aaa53c205c2940004b2"]
```

When I used a database hosted at MongoHQ, the associations work fine. But I don't want to be hosting the app and database separately as network latency adds to every db query's time.

Any ideas what could be wrong and how to fix it?

**Update:**

Mongoid version of appfog is 1.8.5 and
mongoid version on my local machine where it works is 2.2.0.

The following is same for both:

```
m.actors.metadata
=> #<Mongoid::Relations::Metadata
  autobuild:    false
  class_name:   Actor
  cyclic:       nil
  dependent:    nil
  inverse_of:   nil
  key:          actor_ids
  macro:        has_and_belongs_to_many
  name:         actors
  order:        nil
  polymorphic:  false
  relation:     Mongoid::Relations::Referenced::ManyToMany
  setter:       actors=
  versioned:    false>
```

Comment: For which purpose you use mongoid relation?

Comment: Purpose? I'm sorry I didn't get you. I have a few associations in the database like movies having many actors, directors and themes if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @Bornfree Have u set `foreign_key` clause highly unlikely with above code though but still just want to know also can u paste ur model definition also specify the mongoid version in use in appfrog

Comment: @Viren: Kindly look at the update. Also I explicitly added the foreign_key to models.

Comment: @Bornfree Sorry I was looking for the definition of `Mongo` in ur model even though this is good but glimpse of that definition in model would be even better the Model I'm interested is `Movie` in `movie.rb` but do provide the `Actor` model insight as well